# Buying house through assignment of contract

Tags: house-sale

I'm thinking of buying an investment property through an assignment of contract. I plan to do normal inspections and title search, just as I would with a conventional sale.

Assuming title is clean, are there any other risks I should be watching out for related to the assignment of contract deal?

Comment: A country tag might help.

Comment: I was not familiar with purchasing by assigning contract, but an obvious risk seems to be the terms of the contract. There may be clauses in the contract that are detrimental to you or terms that simply aren’t well written and may end up causing an outcome that is detrimental to you because they are challenged, unenforceable, etc.